Move pane right instead of Split right?
I am in a file (File A), and I want to jump to a definition (in File B), so I hit F12, and now I want to see File A and File B side by side. So I have to "Split Right" but then I have to close File B since it's still I the left pane.
Is there a way to "Move right" instead of just "Split Right". How about related things like, "Jump to Definition In New Window" or something like that

What exactly are you looking for? Hotkeys? Actions in general? What exactly should your IDE do on a "Move right"?


There is Split and Move Right action available (that will simply move the current editor tab into the new split. 2) For moving current tab between existing splits -- Move to Opposite group action

